# Git: Usei as credenciais erradas e agora quando tento baixar o repositório SSH, dá fatal

Tags: git, ssh

[image: Falal; Could not read from remote repository]

Ao tentar baixar repositorio em SSH, preenchi as credenciais erradas e agora só aparece esse erro:

```
a assinatura falhou: o agente recusou a operação
git@gitlab.idwall.space: Permissão negada (publickey, teclado interativo).
fatal: não foi possível ler do repositório remoto.

Certifique-se de que possui os direitos de acesso corretos
e o repositório existe.
```

Tentei fazer outra chave SSH, porém não deu certo. O que posso fazer para conseguir clonar o repositório da forma correta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faz o seguinte, vai lá no prompt na raiz do seu projeto e digite o seguinte comando:

```
git config credential.helper store
```

Quando você fizer isso, o console do git vai pedir as credênciais novamente.

Comment: Mas eu não tenho o projeto na minha máquina. To tentando cloná-lo

Comment: vc tem o git bash instalado ai? abre na pasta que vc quer clonar o repo e faz o comando depois tenta clonar. ou se vc tiver acesso ao repo no git cria uma chave ssh usando o comando `ssh-keygen` dai vc pega o pub q ele vai gerar e cadastra sua chave no git dai vc pode clonar usando o shh ao invez do https

Comment: Aparece o erro "fatal: not in a git directory"

Comment: se quiser eu t ajudo pelo anydesk dai eu vejo o q ta acontecendo. so manda o id aqui e quando eu conectar vc apaga a msg

Comment: talvez se vc tentar clonar por https ele vai pedir login e senha do git facilia

Answer (score 1):

Pra resolver foi necessário eu utilizar o `git config --list`. Vi que o meu email não era o correto, já que era o meu email pessoal. Então utilizei o comando abaixo pra remover o antigo email e adicionar o novo:

```
git config --global user.email "MeuEMail"
```

Caso precise modificar o user também:

```
git config --global user.name "SeuUsuario"
```

Tive que fazer outra chave SSH para não dar erro novamente. Assim, resolvi o problema.